# I would like to learn how capture the ID from Get-GPO without the extra lines of "Id : "

Tags: powershell, gpo

I am not finding the way to do this right.  I would like to learn how capture the ID from Get-GPO without the extra lines of "Id : ".  When I was trying to remove the first part; I learned I was working with a "BaseType of System.Object" and not array.  So I have not found any easy way to just remove it or select on the ID it's self without the extra text.
Thank you for you help. 
I do know that "Default Domain Policy" ID is always the same ID)
Here is a sample of what I trying to run and sample of what I would like to get.

```
$test = Get-GPO "Default Domain Policy" | select id
$test
```

---results---

```
Id                                                                                                                                                                                                       
--                                                                                                                                                                                                       
31b2f340-016d-11d2-945f-00c04fb984f9
```

---results I am looking for----

```
31b2f340-016d-11d2-945f-00c04fb984f9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple enough... In your `Select` command use the parameter `-ExpandProperty` (I always just use `-Expand` for short)

```
PS C:\windows\system32> $test = Get-GPO "Default Domain Policy" | select -Expand id | Select -Expand GUID
PS C:\windows\system32> $test

31b2f340-016d-11d2-945f-00c04fb984f9
```

---

The simple answer is:

```
$test = Get-GPO "test1" | select -ExpandProperty id
$Test = $Test.Guid
$test
```

**Edit:** Wow, I left this hanging for 2 years? My bad... To expand on removing blank entries, a GPO object has several properties. One of those properties is `Id`, which is of the type `[System.Guid]`, and has a property of `Guid`, which was the end goal here, to get the GUID of the GPO. The `Guid` property is of type `[System.String]`, and that definitely has a `.Trim()` method. Now, if you have several items, and not all of them have an `Id` property, or not all of the `Id` properties have a `Guid` property, and you iterate through them you will end up with blanks when you output the array. To avoid that we first iterate through the `Id` properties, and then for each of those we iterate through `Guid` properties, and lastly remove extra whitespace in the form of empty strings, null values, and extraneous new lines in a multi-line string (we really shouldn't get any of that last one since these are GUIDs, but I'm just being thorough here).

This time around I will use the shorthand `%` instead of `Select -Expand`. `%` is actually an alias for `ForEach-Object`, and basically what I'm doing here is telling it for each GPO, give me the Id property's value, and then for each of those give me the Guid value.

```
$test = Get-GPO "Default Domain Policy" | % id | % GUID | ?{!([string]::IsNullOrWhitespace($_))} | %{$_.Trim()}
```

When I tested this using `Get-GPO -all`, and output the result I got a wall of just over 1500 GUIDs. No whitespace, no blank lines, just lots and lots of GUIDs.

Comment: Thank you for the responds
| select -Expand id

changes the ID to GUID and still leaves the extra text lines the variable.

Comment: So then pipe it to a Where that clears empty strings, and a ForEach with .Trim().... `$test|Where{!([string]::isnullorempty($_))}|ForEach{$_.trim()}`

Comment: Could you give a more detailed example of yours above, I was not able to get it work.  It was saying

Comment: This is the error I get with "string" or change it to "ID"

Method invocation failed because [Selected.Microsoft.GroupPolicy.Gpo] doesn't contain a method named 'trim'.
At line:2 char:53
+ $test|Where{!([string]::isnullorempty($_))}|ForEach{$_.trim()}
+                                                     ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (trim:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
______
  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem as well and also discovered the same behaviour.
If you use  `-expandproperty ID` (or `(Get-GPO "Default Domain Policy).Id`) you will get `GUID` as your header and no longer `ID`. Crazy PS...

So to me this looked nested.
If you want it "clean" like me because you also don't like trimming as suggested above you can try two options to use in this case:

1. `((Get-GPO "Default Domain Policy").Id).Guid` - my personal preference
2. `(Get-GPO "Default Domain Policy") | select id -ExpandProperty id | select guid -ExpandProperty guid`
   or a mixture of both.

Either one just gives back your GUID as a string.